# asp.net core nested forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, nested-forms

I have 3 models - School, Classrooms & Courses.

A school can have many classrooms, and a classroom can have many courses taught in it.

```
public class School
{
    public int SchoolId { get; set; }
    public string SchoolName { get; set; }
    public List<Classroom> Classrooms { get; set; }
}

public class Classroom
{
    public int ClassroomId { get; set; }
    public string Room { get; set; }
    public List<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public virtual int SchoolId { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public virtual int ClassroomId { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create CRUD actions for School, where I can add 0 to many classrooms and within each classroom create 0 to many courses all in one form.  Allowing the user to dynamically add classrooms and courses within those classrooms all within creating a school

The way that I'm accomplishing this right now is hard coding (where School is the @Model):

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <input asp-for="@Model.SchoolName" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <input asp-for="@Model.Classroom[0].Room" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <input asp-for="@Model.Classroom[0].Course[0].CourseName" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <input asp-for="@Model.Classroom[0].Course[1].CourseName" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <input asp-for="@Model.Classroom[0].Course[3].CourseName" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

I want the user to be able to add more classrooms and more courses or have the ability to remove them dynamically on the form.

Comment: Shouldnt it be the otherway around? Shouldnt the scool have "Courses" instead of classrooms? Does a course have to have an attached classroom fx? Also if your using entity framework - It will automatically create a new table that has the many to many relationship. - Btw its not called "Zero to many" its called "One to many"

Comment: When I say zero to many I'm not referring to a database relation but the List<Course> Courses & List<Classroom> Classrooms, they can have 0 to many items in them.  I'm asking for help with nested forms, so the view part of the MVC pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a partial view and JQuery to create dynamic rows in an html table.

I had a asset transfer form that required at least one line item.  I placed a select list for the assets and a button to add the asset and it's details (the line item) to an html table via a partial view.

Partial View

```html
@model ITFixedAssets.Models.TransferLineItem


@{//this helps with naming the controls within the main view/page
    Models.TransferLineItem TransferLineItem = new Models.TransferLineItem();
   }


<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="padding-right:5px;"  data-action="removeItem" onclick="RemoveRow(this);"></span></a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label asp-for="@TransferLineItem.Id" class="form-control" id="row" style="height:34px;margin-top:5px;"></label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input  asp-for="@TransferLineItem.Asset" class="form-control" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <select asp-for="@TransferLineItem.Condition" class="form-control">
            <option>Please Select</option>
            <option value="New">New</option>
            <option value="Good">Good</option>
            <option value="Bad">Bad</option>
        </select>
        <span asp-validation-for="@TransferLineItem.Condition" class="text-danger"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input asp-for="@TransferLineItem.AssetDescription1" class="form-control" value="@ViewBag.AssetDescription1" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input asp-for="@TransferLineItem.AssetDescription2" class="form-control" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input asp-for="@TransferLineItem.InventoryNum" class="form-control" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input asp-for="@TransferLineItem.SerialNumber" class="form-control" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

When the 'Add Asset' button is clicked it calls a JS function, which uses an ajax GET to run a 'code behind' function that returns the partial view, which is basically a skeleton of a row to be placed into the html table.

JS Function and 'Code Behind' function that returns the partial view.

```js
function AddRow() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Create?handler=AddLineItemRow"
        }).success(function (data) {
           AddNewRow(data);
        });
}
```

```
     public PartialViewResult OnGetAddLineItemRow()
    {
        PartialViewResult partialViewResult = new PartialViewResult();

        partialViewResult.ViewName = "_LineItem";

        return partialViewResult;

    }
```

If successful then the partial view ('data') is passed to another JS function that adds the row to the table and alters the generic id's and names of the controls to the appropriate 'array' style that is needed when the form is submitted in order to save the line items into the database.

```js
//appends the transfer line item table with a new row (partial view)
function AddNewRow(data)
{
    //******************************************************
    //*************add the new to the table**********************
    //append the table with the new row
    $('#LineItems').append(data);
    //******************************************************


    //get value of asset drop down
    var asset = $("#assetList").val();


    //******************************************************
    //*****add the row number to the id values of the controls********

    //get the length of the table for new row # 
    //(subtract 1, not sure why unless it's adding the headers into the count)
    var rowNum = $("#LineItems tr").length - 1;

    //build new name to add to the controls
    var nameIndex = rowNum - 1;
    var newName = "[" + nameIndex + "].";

    //get the row label
    var lblRow = $("#row");

    //create new id for the row label
    var newId = "row_" + rowNum;

    //apply new id
    lblRow.attr("id", newId);

    //get the last row in the table
    var lastRow = $("#LineItems").find("tr").last();

    ////format id values for the input controls
    //and add names for the controls 
    lastRow.find("input").each(function () {

        // get id of this input control
        var ctrl = $(this).attr("id");

        //concatenate the row number to the id
        var newId = ctrl + "_" + rowNum;

        //assign new id to control
        $(this).attr("id", newId);

        //add the index to the control'
        $(this).attr("name",$(this).attr("name").replace(".", newName));
        

    });

    //update the select list (for condition) id value
    var selectControl = lastRow.find("select");

    //get id of the select control
    var scId = selectControl.attr("id");

    //concatenate the row number to the id
    newId = scId + "_" + rowNum;

    //assign new id to control
    selectControl.attr("id", newId);

    //add new name to control
    selectControl.attr("name", selectControl.attr("name").replace(".", newName));

    //this ajax calls the function 'OnGetPopulateLineItemRow' in the code behind
    //and passes the asset # and row # as parameters.  the success function 
    //receives the return value from the OnGetPopulateItemRow function and 
    //passes that 'data' to the PopulateRow function below
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "Create?handler=PopulateLineItemRow",
        data: { _asset: asset },
        //data: { _asset: asset, row: rowNum }
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            PopulateRow(asset, data, rowNum);
        }
    });

}
```

After the new row has been added to the table and the names and id's are changed, another ajax 'GET' is used to call a 'code behind' function to to get the values for the controls in the new row (as can be seen in the above snippet).

Function that gets the item details of the Asset

```
 public JsonResult OnGetPopulateLineItemRow(string _asset)
    {

        //stores named value pairs for the result
        Dictionary<string, string> results = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        //get record from the database for the specified asset (_asset)
        var asset = from a in _context.Asset select a;
        asset = asset.Where(a => a.Asset1 == _asset); 

        //get value for each field
        var description1 = from d in asset select d.AssetDescription;
        var description2 = from d in asset select d.AssetDescription2;
        var inventoryNum = from d in asset select d.InventoryNo;
        var serialNum = from s in asset select s.SerialNo;

        //add the name value pairs to the collection
        results.Add("description1", description1.ToList()[0].ToString());
        results.Add("description2", description2.ToList()[0].ToString());
        results.Add("inventoryNum", inventoryNum.ToList()[0].ToString());
        results.Add("serialNum", serialNum.ToList()[0].ToString());


        return new JsonResult(results);

    }
```

Finally these results are passed back to the success function and JQuery is used to populate the values

```js
function PopulateRow(asset, data,rowNum) {

    $("#row" + "_" + rowNum).text($("#LineItems tr").length - 1);
    $("#TransferLineItem_Asset" + "_" + rowNum).val(asset);
    $("#TransferLineItem_AssetDescription1" + "_" + rowNum).val(data["description1"]);
    $("#TransferLineItem_AssetDescription2" + "_" + rowNum).val(data["description2"]);
    $("#TransferLineItem_InventoryNum" + "_" + rowNum).val(data["inventoryNum"]);
    $("#TransferLineItem_SerialNumber" + "_" + rowNum).val(data["serialNum"]);

    //reset drop down
    $('#assetList').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
}
```

Just as a side note.  Until recently I used ASP.net webforms.  I'm still trying to understand how to accomplish what I considered to be simple things with server side coding that really, to me, seem to be more complicated with MVC and Razor.

Comment: While this may answer the (one year old) question, you may expand your answer with more text, code sippets and documentation. Please edit your question :)